# Simulate V1838B IR LED output

Tags: pwm, attiny, ir, attiny85, infrared

I have a HDMI switcher which uses a TL1338 IR LED that's connected via a 3.5mm audio jack. It has its own remote for switching between the inputs, but I want to use my TV remote.

In order to do that I want to connect the IR led to an ATTiny85 to receive the input and send the 'translated'code to the switcher.

When analysed with an oscilloscope it seemed that Arduino Libraries output a PWM signal, while the TL1838 outputs a digital signal. Is there a way to simulate a TL1838 signal?

Original situation:
[image: Original situation]

Goal situation with ATTiny85.
[image: Updated situation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is send "unmodulated" IR Codes, but the library is trying to modulate them with a 38khz carrier. (The TL1838 device has a built-in demodulator.)

While your question is not a duplicate, [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18582/how-to-send-unmodulated-ir-signal-via-cable) applies.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that I have the term unmodulated I can research more in the right direction as well. It's also a very complete answer.